# how to write hello world servlet Example

Tags: java, servlets

javaclass

```
package com.example;

import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

// Extend HttpServlet class
public class Helloworld extends HttpServlet {
    private String message;

    public void init() throws ServletException {
        // Do required initialization
        message = "Hello World";
    }

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // Set response content type
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        // Actual logic goes here.
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<h1>" + message + "</h1>");
    }

    public void destroy() {
        // do nothing.
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>HelloForm</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>HelloForm</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloForm</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/HelloForm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Give is code But i run the Project  There is no Output comes 404 Error is comes in web Page . we need create Jsp Page also for servlet? I am really new in Servlet Please help how to write hello world is Servlet .

Comment: Shouldn't `servlet-class` be `Helloworld`?  Being awhile since I did this kind of thing...

Comment: Don't try to re-edit the question based on answer received. Else all of below answers will become invalid.

Answer (score 9):

You have created servlet class like this:

```
public class Helloworld extends HttpServlet
```

But in web.xml you have mapping like this:

```
<servlet-class>HelloForm</servlet-class>
```

You need to have same name, so you're getting 404 error. Change either your servlet name to `HelloForm` or change `<servlet-class>` to `HelloWorld`in web.xml

Comment: What is the url you're giving?

Comment: Nope that's not correct. Try giving localhost:8080/ServlteExample/HelloWorld

Comment: Try restarting server? and what's your project name?

Comment: ServlteExample is my Project name can u please mail me one simplehello world Example

Comment: maklee322@gmail.com in this email id please

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-first-example.htm this may help you

Comment: can u please do this and mail me so that i can Understand where am doing mistake

Answer (score 3):

Your class resides in *com.example*

So servlet-class should,

```
<servlet-class>com.example.Helloworld</servlet-class>
```

Comment: Only we have to change this?

Comment: Yes looks like only this change should suffice. And also you are deploying it in the container (tomcat or jboss), so if you face issues post the error logs too.

Answer (score 2):

Use following :

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>HelloForm</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.Helloworld</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloForm</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/HelloForm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and type your url: like `localhost:8080/projectName/HelloForm` It may work. And I think you are beginner so go [This link](http://www.scribd.com/doc/131467470/Servlet) . Here is complete tutorial...aboutt this

Comment: I have changed it Like this :<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app>
  <display-name>Helloworld</display-name>
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Helloworld</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.Helloworld</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Helloworld</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Helloworld</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>

Comment: @user2782773 Show up your directory tree :)

Answer (score 2):

Now you can switch to servlet 3.0. It's really simple.

```
@WebServlet("/example")
public class AnnotationServlet extends HttpServlet{

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter prinOut = response.getWriter();
        prinOut.write("Hello, This is the first servlet 3 annotation example");
    }

}
```

From [Servlet 3.0 Annotation Example in Java](http://javabycode.com/java-frameworks/servlet-jsp/servlet-3-0-annotation-example.html)

And here is full [Java Servlet Tutorial](http://javabycode.com/java-frameworks/servlet-jsp/java-servlet-tutorial-java-servlet-example.html)

Answer (score 0):

you haven't specified the package of the servlet class
write like this
com.example.Helloworld

Comment: still not working i have changed package name com.example.Helloworld

Answer (score 0):

Following way will work.

Create a folder(your poject name,example project) in webapps
Inside proect folder create another folder,name it as WEB-INF.
Inside WEB-INF past the web.inf file.
Create another folder classes inside project folder and keep the .class files.
now modify your web.xml as Himanshu Bhardwaj has suggested.
restart the server.Then run

Comment: I did restart server still not working i Dont know where doing mistake while i have just copy and paste Example from Google we need create JSp page for this ?

Comment: @user2782773 have you done the folder structure as i have suggested

Comment: I am doing it Eclipsed it alredy set like this

Comment: @user2782773 which server you are using?

Comment: @user2782773 Then in go the tomcat folder,find webapps folder,do as i said.restart the server and run your app

Comment: I did friend But am not  getting Out put can u please Provide me one saimple Example of hello world in this id  maklee322@gmail.com please

Comment: @user2782773 I am not allowed to access email at work,well you post another question in stackoverflow .There are other users also who will defintely help you.