# Data show on servlet, not on jsp?

Tags: sql-server-2008

**Hi there,
My task is displaying a list of object from database to JSP. But i don't know why it only show when i run servlet class,while not show anything when i run JSP. First I used setAttribute method to pass the list to JSP and at JSP i use JSTL tags for retriving data. I think everything is ok but don't why it happend like that. Here's my code**

Asiakas.java

```js
package Luokat;

public class Asiakas {
 private int asiakas_id;
 private String nimi;
 private int puhelinnumero;
 private String spostiosoite;
 /**
  * 
  */
 public Asiakas() {
  asiakas_id = 0;
  nimi= null;
  puhelinnumero =0;
  spostiosoite = null;
 }
 /**
  * @param asiakas_id
  * @param nimi
  * @param puhelinnumero
  * @param spostiosoite
  */
 public Asiakas(int asiakas_id, String nimi, int puhelinnumero,
   String spostiosoite) {
  super();
  this.asiakas_id = asiakas_id;
  this.nimi = nimi;
  this.puhelinnumero = puhelinnumero;
  this.spostiosoite = spostiosoite;
 }
 public int getAsiakas_id() {
  return asiakas_id;
 }
 public void setAsiakas_id(int asiakas_id) {
  this.asiakas_id = asiakas_id;
 }
 public String getNimi() {
  return nimi;
 }
 public void setNimi(String nimi) {
  this.nimi = nimi;
 }
 public int getPuhelinnumero() {
  return puhelinnumero;
 }
 public void setPuhelinnumero(int puhelinnumero) {
  this.puhelinnumero = puhelinnumero;
 }
 public String getSpostiosoite() {
  return spostiosoite;
 }
 public void setSpostiosoite(String spostiosoite) {
  this.spostiosoite = spostiosoite;
 }
 
 
 @Override
 public String toString() {
  return "Asiakas [asiakas_id=" + asiakas_id + ", nimi=" + nimi
    + ", puhelinnumero=" + puhelinnumero + ", spostiosoite="
    + spostiosoite + "]";
 }
 

}
```

NaytaAsiakasServlet

```js
    package Servletit;



    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

    import DBHoitaja.DBHoitaja;
    import Luokat.Asiakas;



    /**
     * Servlet implementation class NaytaAsiakasServlet
     */
    @WebServlet("/NaytaAsiakasServlet")
    public class NaytaAsiakasServlet extends HttpServlet {
     private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
     /**
         * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
         */
        public NaytaAsiakasServlet() {
            super();
            
           }

     /**
      * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
      */
     protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
      NaytaAsiakasServlet nayta = new NaytaAsiakasServlet();
      request.setAttribute("asiakasLista", nayta.findAll());
            request.getRequestDispatcher("admin_page.jsp").forward(request, response);
      }

     /**
      * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
      */
     public List<Asiakas> findAll(){
      List<Asiakas> list = new ArrayList<Asiakas>();
      try {
       list.add(new Asiakas(0, "Kaísa",0445206766,"kaisaa@haaga-helia.fi"));
       list.add(new Asiakas(1, "Kaísa",0445206766,"kaisaa@haaga-helia.fi"));
       list.add(new Asiakas(3, "Kaísa",0445206766,"kaisaa@haaga-helia.fi"));

       
      } catch(Exception e){
       list =null;
      }
      return list;
     }
     
     protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     }

    }
```

admin_page.jsp

```js
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
        pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Ylläpito Sivu</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" width="500">
    <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Nimi</th>
    <th>Puhelin</th>
    <th>Sähköposti</th>
    </tr>


    <c:forEach var="asiakas" items="${asiakasLista}" >
    <tr>
    <td><c:out value="${asiakas.asiakas_id}" /></td>
    <td><c:out value="${asiakas.nimi}" /></td>
    <td><c:out value="${asiakas.puhelinnumero}" /></td>
    <td><c:out value="${asiakas.spostiosoite}" /></td>
    </tr>
    </c:forEach>
    </table>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question I can understand that you are totally new to J2EE!! And also you are trying to run the servlet class and JSP, which is not going to work anyway.

Please read the below specified tutorials and have some idea on how run a simple web application.
[how to write hello world servlet Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18821227/how-to-write-hello-world-servlet-example)

[Sample Code for Hello World:](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-first-example.htm)

Comment: Thank for replying. I've solved this issue. This's my misunderstanding about server side between client side. When run JSP, it doesn't show anything because at that time the controller still haven't be called.