# Web appilcation connection to external server?

Tags: java

So I have two Java applications, a server and a client. They are simple programs no GUI elements just console applications. They work just fine running on my machine, and I have a client version that can even connect to the server via the internet.

[image: picasso]

Instead of hosting the Server on my local machine I would like to host it from a site like Openshift. Which I already have a HTML site up at using Tomcat 7. I would also like to be able to go to a page on the web server and have that page act as the client program.

[image: monet]

I want to embedded the client program into the web server but....

How do I make the connection between the two servers? Pretty much how do I get the Web Page to reach out to the other server and make the connection(I am using sockets)? Do I need to be  using a servlet, JSP, or something like Jquery?

If you feel like you need to see either the server program or the client let me know and I will post them.

Comment: The question is clear and conscise, but does not really fit here. You would have better luck trying, then asking how to solve specific issues.

Comment: Are there 2 servers here or 1? You mentioned that you wanted to use the 3rd-party-hosting, but is it necessary for you to keep using the second server? It's possible you could do this without any remote connection.

Comment: why would you want to go through a web server? Your server program - if it uses Sockets - can simply run on another server, your clients would need to specify the target IP address or hostname and it would work the same way as your first drawing.

Comment: @4castle Yes there is a need for the remote connection, because along with the ability to connect would be through a web page and then through a mobile application(not mention here because I don't want to muddy the waters)

Comment: @geert3 Yes it does use sockets, however, I would like to host a client version on the web page. The best was I know to describe it would be the "client program embedded inside the page on the web server", so the data returned from the other server is displayed inside the page.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard thank you for the compliment, however, I have tried to have a JSP show a button that you click on, a Jquery script that calls a java servlet, that in the doPost function creates the server object at "localhost". The sever object then listens in on its sever socket for a client to connect. However, I ran the client program to connect and it threw an refused connection error. Does that mean that the server is up? There reason I asked the question was because I thought my design was wrong....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to host a client version on the web page.

Your JSP or servlet would be the client in that case, it would open a socket to the server process. Have a look at `HttpServlet` and its `doGet` method, this is basically what you would implement, and where you would place much of your client code, like opening a socket to your server process and returning data. You'll find tons of examples on the internet, see for instance

[how to write hello world servlet Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18821227/how-to-write-hello-world-servlet-example)

Browsing to the servlet's URL will invoke the doGet method and execute your client code. It should be stateless though, i.e. take whatever parameters are in the HttpServletRequest, do its thing based on that, and return as soon as possible. If your clients need to retain their connection to the server process, it will be a different story, and you may need for instance websockets (I have insufficient experience with that but it would sound like a good fit in that case).

Comment: Due to the behavior of the client program and the server, I am going to say that your second course of action is the way to go. I am gonna explain to see if you agree. The server sends broadcasts to each client based on a update to 'state' by one of the clients. ie. client 1 submits an update to the server, server broadcasts that update to client 1 and 2. Web sockets hmm.... is that a part of the servlet package? Or are you talking about Sockets and Server sockets in  java.net?

Comment: websockets is a rather new technology that is part of the Servlet spec since v.3.1  - it is used to make a continuous connection between the browser and the web server / servlet, so the browser can receive notifications from the server without having to do a request first ("push"). There would be a (regular) socket connection between your web server and your "server process". The websocket would be used to transfer the notifications down to your browser.

Comment: I don't know if you would like to include this in your answer. [WebSocket Tutorial](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/HomeWebsocket/WebsocketHome.html)